# Windbg managed objects poi for arrays first element, second element

Tags: windbg, sos

I can use `poi` in windbg scripting to traverse the fields and then print the field i am interested in.
For e.g. if i have all objects of type `X` which has field `X.y.z` where `z` is an array, where `y` is at offset `0x10` and `z` is at offset `0x8`. I can write

```
.foreach ( dSM { !dumpheap -short -type X})
 { 
    .printf "%p\n", poi(poi(${dSM}+0x10)+0x8); 
    !dumparray poi(poi(${dSM}+0x10)+0x8)     
}
```

Now i want to print first/second element of all these arrays, how can i do that ?

using `!do poi(poi(poi(${dSM}+0x10)+0x8))` does not work.

```
0:045> !DumpArray /d 000001d3b96787a8
Name:        ABC[]
MethodTable: 00007ffc951e76e0
EEClass:     00007ffcf22f4480
Size:        56(0x38) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 4, Type CLASS
Element Methodtable: 00007ffc951e6cc0
[0] 000001d3b9678788
[1] null
[2] null
[3] null
0:045> !dumpobj /d poi(000001d3b96787a8)
<Note: this object has an invalid CLASS field>
Invalid object
```

Array class is:

```
:045> !DumpClass /d 00007ffcf22f4480
Class Name:      System.Object[]
mdToken:         0000000002000000
File:            C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Parent Class:    00007ffcf22f5018
Module:          00007ffcf2221000
Method Table:    00007ffcf2949e80
Vtable Slots:    18
Total Method Slots:  1c
Class Attributes:    2101  
Transparency:        Transparent
NumInstanceFields:   0
NumStaticFields:     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this program:

```
using System;

namespace WinDbgArrayAccess
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Program[] justAnArray = new Program[20];
            for (int i =0; i<justAnArray.Length;i++) justAnArray[i] = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine("Access the elements of the array in WinDbg now!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see

```
0:006> !DumpArray /d 0336243c
Name:        WinDbgArrayAccess.Program[]
MethodTable: 01914db0
EEClass:     71967820
Size:        92(0x5c) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 20, Type CLASS
Element Methodtable: 01914d60
[0] 03362498
[1] 033624a4
[2] 033624b0
[3] 033624bc
[4] 033624c8
[5] 033624d4
...
```

Now you need to find those numbers somewhere in the memory. Since we hardly have a different starting point, let's start at the array's address:

```
0:006> dp 0336243c L10
0336243c  01914db0 00000014 03362498 033624a4
0336244c  033624b0 033624bc 033624c8 033624d4
0336245c  033624e0 033624ec 033624f8 03362504
0336246c  03362510 0336251c 03362528 03362534
```

Now, `01914db0` is the type of the object (called Method Table, MT). `0x14` is `0n20`, which is the size of the array. And after that, it seems we have the elements, `03362498`, `033624a4`, `033624b0` etc.

How do we access that programmatically? Well, it's easy now:

```
0:006> .printf "%p",poi(0336243c+(2+3)*$ptrsize)
033624bc
```

Where `2` is to skip MT and Length and `3` is the index of the array, giving you the 4th element.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your approach.. This will help me in future.

Comment: I did it with : `.foreach (obj { !DumpHeap -short -live -mt 00007ffc951e7ab8}) { .printf "%p\n", ${obj}; !mex.do2 poi(poi(poi(poi(${obj}+0x10)+0x8)+0x10)+0x8); !mex.do2 poi(poi(poi(poi(${obj}+0x10)+0x8)+0x10)+0x10); }` .. `going +10+8` and `+10+10` for first 2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get first 2 elements by going forward `poi(poi(array+10)+8)` and `poi(poi(array+10)+10)` offsets from array

```
0:298> .foreach (obj { !DumpHeap -short -live -mt 00007ffc951e7ab8}) { .printf "%p\n", ${obj}; !mex.do2 poi(poi(poi(poi(${obj}+0x10)+0x8)+0x10)+0x8); !mex.do2 poi(poi(poi(poi(${obj}+0x10)+0x8)+0x10)+0x10); }
000001d379ac94a0
[raw] 000001d379ac8bc8 "XYZ_String"
[raw] 000001d379ac8c88 "XYZ_String_2"
000001d379e87168
[raw] 000001d379e86888 "ABCD_String"
[raw] 000001d379e86948 "ABCD_String_2"
000001d3b972a218
```